# Convert RT90 into WGS84

Tags: sql, sql-server, coordinate-system

Goal:
Gain WGS84 decimal to locate some cities in Google Map.

Problem:
I don't know how to convert the value of the RT90 coordinate system into WGS84 in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page may be of assistance:

[Translate coordinates between RT90, WGS84 and SWEREF99 using .NET](http://blog.sallarp.com/translate-coordinates-between-rt90-wgs84-and-sweref99-using-net/)

Edit: Archive.org link: https://web.archive.org/web/20120510114228/http://blog.sallarp.com/translate-coordinates-between-rt90-wgs84-and-sweref99-using-net/

Comment: Link is dead so the answer is useless. Please put the content into the answer along with the link.

Answer (score 1):

in postgis you can use this sql query for RT90(SRID=3021) to WGS84(SRID=4326) :

```
Select * From ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(6403554, 6403554), 3021), 4326) as lonlat
```

---

```
Select * From ST_X(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(6403554, 6403554), 3021), 4326)) as
    lon, ST_Y(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(6403554, 6403554), 3021), 4326)) as lat
```

beside this you can check out [this](https://loceo.se/doc/rt90) REST-service which converts coordinates between RT90 (Rikets Triangelnät or Swedish Grid) and WGS84 decimal.

for example:

```
https://loceo.se/api/wgs84?x=6403550&y=1271824

{
  provider:[
    "Loceo",
    "WGS84"
  ],
  geometry:{
    type:"Point",
    coordinates:[
      57.6987586,
      11.97738784
    ]
  }
}
```

and the last thing is that i want to say, you can use [SQL Server Spatial Tools](http://sqlspatialtools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Current%20Contents&referringTitle=Home) for 
querying spatial queries...

i hope it helps you....